# Center and Vertically align input fields in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input, vertical-alignment

I have a set of input fields:

```
    <p>
        <input type="image" src="images/text_to_speech.svg" alt="Speak This" width="48" height="48" id="say_button"></input>

        <input type="text" value="" class="input-lg" id="say_utterance" placeholder="Enter text to speak..."></input>

        <span id="say_remaining"></span>
    </p>
```

It's not aligned vertically. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the minimal code you provided, it's actually your image causing the issue.  Add `vertical-align:middle;` to it and the rest will center out.  [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/JUmPPzkDBJ).

Comment: That's not the bootstrap way to do it, this is a simple overwrite with custom css.

Comment: @user2521387  While this is true, *For the minimal code*.... I'm working with what he gave.  Not assuming that adding a bunch of extras is an option.

Comment: OK, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this inside a div instead of p.

```
<div class="vcenter">
<input type="image" src="images/text_to_speech.svg" alt="Speak This" width="48" height="48" id="say_button"></input>

        <input type="text" value="" class="input-lg" id="say_utterance" placeholder="Enter text to speak..."></input>

        <span id="say_remaining"></span>
</div>
```

the style

```
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use Bootstrap, if you don't use it?

Here is a plain example of how Bootstrap gives you some tools/input classes for form to do it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="radio" aria-label="...">
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

You need to wrap your input fields in a row, then create 2 columns via `col-lg-6` for 2 container which will be 12 columns in total and give both input fields line-equal / vertical spacing.

Don't forget to wrap your input fields with a div with the class `input-group`